# Fight against circular dependency with get_it on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, circular-dependency

GetIt is *Service Locator for Dart and Flutter projects* (https://github.com/fluttercommunity/get_it)

I think GetIt should give us some details about circular dependency.

When I run my tests for example there is an infinite loop and they never end.

Answer (score 7):

The get_it is for defining global objects and services, and for providing a locator functionality with which to access them. If you have a circular dependency among your global services, there's a good chance that you have designed those services to be tightly coupled with each other. For example:

```dart
class ServiceA {
  final ServiceB b;

  ServiceA(this.b);

  void foo() {
    b.bar();
  }

  void bar() { ... }
}

class ServiceB {
  final ServiceA a;

  ServiceB(this.a);

  void foo() {
    a.bar();
  }

  void bar() { ... }
}

// GetIt Initialization

GetIt g = GetIt.instance;
g.registerLazySingleton<ServiceA>(() => ServiceA(g.get<ServiceB>()));
g.registerLazySingleton<ServiceB>(() => ServiceB(g.get<ServiceA>()));
```

After this, calling `GetIt.I.get` targeting either `ServiceA` or `ServiceB` could create the infinite loop caused by circular dependency. With this implementation, there's no real way to prevent the loop without going down a rabbit hole of checks and deferred execution.

The real solution to circular dependency is often simple: design your app to not have it in the first place. For example, in the above example, `ServiceA` has a rigid dependency on `ServiceB` in the constructor and vice versa. Instead, the services could use a service locator to instead fetch the reference to the necessary service during execution of the method that needs it. To put that another way, we already are using get_it, so why not use it here?

```dart
class ServiceA {
  ServiceA();

  void foo() {
    final b = GetIt.I.get<ServiceB>();
    b.bar();
  }

  void bar() { ... }
}

class ServiceB {
  ServiceB();

  void foo() {
    final a = GetIt.I.get<ServiceA>();
    a.bar();
  }
}

// GetIt Initialization

GetIt g = GetIt.instance;
g.registerLazySingleton<ServiceA>(() => ServiceA());
g.registerLazySingleton<ServiceB>(() => ServiceB());
```

Now the dependencies that `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` have on each other is much more dynamic and is not tied to their respective constructors. There is no longer a circular dependency problem, and the get_it initializer will have no problem initializing the singletons when they are accessed.

Comment: I think get_it should detect circular dependencies in order to notify the developer.

Comment: @Pierre-LucBLOT How would get_it on its own be able to detect circular dependencies? The locator/initializer cannot get information on the types themselves without reflection. Any detection method (yours included) would require that the types themselves implement a custom getter method. Maybe the package can provide that utility, but then the circular detection would only work on types that actually use it. This is a highly niche feature that requires people to actually know about it in order to implement and even then it only provides a runtime error instead of any actual protection.

Comment: Thanks, @Abion47 .. you made my day ;)

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem. Here a part solution with this example:

Some interfaces and implementations:

```dart
abstract class SuperLetter {}

abstract class A implements SuperLetter {}

class AC implements A {
  final B b;
  AC({this.b});

  @override
  String toString() {
    if (b == null) {
      return "Im an A.";
    }
    return "Im an A and my B is: $b";
  }
}

abstract class B implements SuperLetter {}

class BC implements B {
  final C c;
  BC({this.c});

  @override
  String toString() {
    if (c == null) {
      return "Im a B.";
    }
    return "Im a B and my C: $c";
  }
}

abstract class C implements SuperLetter {}

class CC implements C {

  final SuperLetter a;
  CC({this.a});

  @override
  String toString() {
    if (a == null) {
      return "Im a C.";
    }
    return "Im a C and my A: $a"; // might never be reached because of circular dependency
  }
}
```

A new Exception to throw when circular dependency is detected.

```dart
class CircularDependencyException implements Exception {
  final wantedType;
  final calledTypes;

  CircularDependencyException({
    this.wantedType,
    this.calledTypes,
  });

  @override
  String toString() {
    String message = ' Circular dependency ';
    for (final e in calledTypes) {
      message += '${e.toString()}';
      if (e == calledTypes.last) {
        message += ' -> $wantedType';
      } else {
        message += ' -> ';
      }
    }
    return message;
  }
}
```

To fight against circular dependency:

```dart
class GetItProtector {
  var _wantedType;
  Set _calledTypes;
  final GetIt getIt;

  GetItProtector(this.getIt);

  _check<T>() {
    if (_wantedType == null) {
      _wantedType = T;
      _calledTypes = Set()..add(T);
    } else {
      if (_calledTypes.contains(T)) {
        throw CircularDependencyException(wantedType: T, calledTypes: _calledTypes);
      }
      _calledTypes.add(T);
    }
  }

  T call<T>() {
    _check<T>();
    final instance = getIt<T>();
    if (instance.runtimeType == _wantedType) {
      _wantedType = null;
      _calledTypes.clear();
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Example with A -> B -> C -> A circular dependency:

```dart
void main() {
  GetIt g = GetIt.instance;
  final myGet = GetItProtector(g);
  g.registerLazySingleton<A>(() => AC(
        b: myGet(),
      ));

  g.registerLazySingleton<B>(() => BC(
        c: myGet(),
      ));

  g.registerLazySingleton<C>(() => CC(
        a: myGet<A>(),
      ));

  A a = myGet();
  print(a);
}
```

Output:

```
Error while creating C
Stack trace: ......

Error while creating B
Stack trace: ......

Error while creating A
Stack trace: ......

Unhandled exception:
 Circular dependency A -> B -> C -> A
....
```

Example with A -> B -> C -> B

```dart
void main() {
  GetIt g = GetIt.instance;
  final myGet = GetItProtector(g);
  g.registerLazySingleton<A>(() => AC(
        b: myGet(),
      ));

  g.registerLazySingleton<B>(() => BC(
        c: myGet(),
      ));

  g.registerLazySingleton<C>(() => CC(
        a: myGet<B>(),
      ));

  A a = myGet();
  print(a);
}
```

Output

```
Error while creating C
Stack trace: ......

Error while creating B
Stack trace: ......

Error while creating A
Stack trace: ......

Unhandled exception:
 Circular dependency A -> B -> C -> B
....
```

In this solution I don't test if type is a real type and not Object or dynamic.

Comment: This isn't a solution so much as it is a slightly convoluted way to identify the problem.