# How to solve this circular dependency in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

AuthRepository -> AuthDataSource -> ApiClient -> AuthInterceptor -> AuthRepository

The objective here is to implement network request interception in AuthInterceptor. Specifically, if the response code is 401 (indicating an unauthenticated state), the interceptor should trigger a call to AuthRepository.logout().

[image]

**Code:**

```
final sl = GetIt.instance; // sl is short for service locator

sl.registerLazySingleton<AuthInterceptor>(() => AuthInterceptor(authRepository: sl()));

sl.registerLazySingleton<ApiClient>(
      () => ApiClient(dio: Dio(), preferencesService: sl(), authInterceptor: sl(), tokenStorage: sl()));

sl.registerLazySingleton<AuthRepository>(() => AuthRepositoryImpl(authDataSource: sl()));

sl.registerLazySingleton<AuthDataSource>(() => AuthRemoteDataSourceImpl(apiClient: sl()));
```

Comment: Solve what?  What problem are you encountering?  Can you provide code that can reproduce it?

Comment: @jamesdlin I have added the code in my post.

Comment: @FaizanMalik I think james means implementation-level code not singleton registration.

Comment: I want to see code that can reproduce the problem you're encountering (and you still haven't described what the problem is).

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. And this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64213423/15605026) helped. You can use **GetIt** inside your functions of classes, and simply do not send objects into constructors.